# T-SQL ISNULL() incorrect behaviour with reserved word 'Primary' (SQL Server 2014)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, isnull

I came across this the other day, and it wasn't a major as  I could work around it, but wondered if anyone could offer any insight, or have I found an obscure bug?

We have an old database table that has a column called Primary, which is obviously a reserved word. When running a T-SQL query I came across some weird results which seems to suggest that the ISNULL function is treating the column name as if it were the reserved word. Is it just because it's late on Friday and I'm missing something really obvious here, or is something weird going on here?

Here is some simple SQL to set up a couple of test tables to illustrate it.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer]
(
    [CustomerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CustomerID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderTaken]
(
    [OrderID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Primary] [bit] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Order] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([OrderID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderTaken] WITH CHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Customer] 
   FOREIGN KEY([CustomerID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([CustomerID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderTaken] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Customer]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customer](Name) VALUES('Bob')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customer](Name) VALUES('Dave')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customer](Name) VALUES('Fred')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customer](Name) VALUES('Paul')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrderTaken](Description, CustomerID, [Primary]) 
VALUES ('Order1', 1, 1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrderTaken](Description, CustomerID, [Primary]) 
VALUES('Order2', 2, 1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrderTaken](Description, CustomerID, [Primary]) 
VALUES('Order3', 2, 1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrderTaken](Description, CustomerID, [Primary]) 
VALUES('Order4', 3, 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrderTaken](Description, CustomerID, [Primary]) 
VALUES('Order5', 3, 0)
Go
```

and here is the query

```
SELECT 
    C.CustomerID, C.Name,
    O.OrderID, ISNULL(O.[OrderID], -1),
    O.[Primary], ISNULL(O.[Primary], -1) as Weird
FROM 
    Customer C
LEFT JOIN 
    OrderTaken O ON C.CustomerID  = O.CustomerID
```

Notice that for the customer row that doesn't have an Order, O.Primary is NULL , but ISNULL(O.[Primary],-1) returns 1 and not -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not in field name, it's in field type - `bit`.
It cant hold `-1` value, only `0` and `1`. And when SQL Server tries to change value to `-1` it checks that `-1 <> 0` and sets `1` (`true`). See [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177603(v=sql.120).aspx).

So convert the field before checking:

```
SELECT 
    C.CustomerID,
    C.Name,
    O.OrderID,
    ISNULL(O.[OrderID],-1),
    O.[Primary],
    ISNULL(CONVERT(int,O.[Primary]),-1) as Weird
FROM Customer C
LEFT JOIN OrderTaken O
ON C.CustomerID  = O.CustomerID
```

Or change column type to `int` or `tinyint`.

Comment: Doh !  So it was that it was late on a  Friday and I should have looked at it on Monday. Cheers for setting me straight {:O)